# Promedio en SSAS con MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Hola estoy tratando de sacar un promedio en Analysis Services pero no se agrupa de la manera correcta. Mi formula es la siguiente:

```
([Measures].[Asientos]/[Measures].[Pasajeros])*([Measures].[Distancia]/[Measures].[Pasajeros])
```

Y haciendo el análisis del cubo me muestra los siguientes resultados dndome un total de 12356736 en la columna de ASK lo cual es correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si lo agrupo por ruta me da un resultado menor lo cual es incorrecto, debería de ser el mismo total y un acumulado mayor para cada ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]